# How to get the Public IP

Tags: php, ip-address

I'm trying to get the Public IP of someone that use the form of the page I do.

I don't know with which programming language would do that. I was reading on the web and I found some:

```
// PHP Code
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

This outputs: 127.0.0.1 (Local IP).

Then I found this too:

```
// PHP Code
$externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
preg_match('/\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b/', $externalContent, $m);
$externalIp = $m[0];
```

This outputs the correct IP (Public IP), but that needs to use other web page (http://checkip.dyndns.com/).

I wonder How do the pages like that get the Public IP?. I am looking for a way to get it without need to use other web page. Thanks.

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER);`

Comment: Do you get to you server by `http://localhost`? Than you will not get anything except of `127.0.0.1` In order to get IP of the connected user, he should connect not through the loopback address. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Why can't you use other webpages? The second method works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Cheery thanks you have the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` should work fine for what you are trying to do here. The reason you are getting 127.0.0.1 is because you are running this in a local environment.

If you put this script on a live webserver and I access it, you will get the same IP from `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` as I get when I check [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/)

And anyhow, having the server call:

```
$externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
```

will only get you successful in returning your servers IP address, not the visitors.

Comment: Thanks. So now How should be to get the Visitors IP?

Comment: $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] contains the IP address of the computer accessing your webserver. The only reason you got 127.0.0.1 would be because you ran it locally

Answer (score 0):

This problem had me stumped for a long while.

If you have access to your own remote server, what I did to solve this problem was create a simple server-side script  `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` to give me the public IP assigned by my ISP to my device from my localhost.